# remove spaces from char* array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am working on a plugin in `C` for a game emulator, where I would like to remove all spaces from chat message before checking if the input messages contain any website urls.

So, I have this function like this to deblank (remove spaces from input message):

```
char* deblank(char* input) {
    int i, j;
    char *output = input;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(input); i++, j++) {
        if (input[i] != ' ')
            output[j] = input[i];
        else
            j--;
    }
    output[j] = 0;
    return output;
}
```

I use it in my plugin hook like this:

```
bool my_pc_process_chat_message(bool retVal___, struct map_session_data *sd, const char *message) {
    if (retVal___ == true) {
        char* check_message = deblank(message);
        bool url_detected = (stristr(check_message, "://") || stristr(check_message, "www.") || stristr(check_message, "vvvvvv.") || stristr(check_message, "wvvw."));
        if (!url_detected) {
            int len = sizeof(tld_list) / sizeof(tld_list[0]);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                if (stristr(check_message, tld_list[i])) {
                    url_detected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (url_detected) {
            clif->messagecolor_self(sd->fd, COLOR_RED, "Possible GM Impersonation Detected - you cannot type website URLs in chat.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return retVal___;
}
```

The above works, but there's a side-effect. What seems to be happening is that the input message is getting modified and all spaces from the message being removed, when it doesn't contain any website urls.

For example, if I typed:

> Go to www.some-domain.com

The above get's blocked, So does this (when players try to be clever and use spaces):

> w w w . s o m e      -       d o m a i n . c o m

However, when you type a normal message that doesn't contain any website urls like this:

> Hello, how are you?

It's getting turned into the following:

> Hello,howareyou?

This is because of this line: `char* check_message = deblank(message);`
The deblank function appears to be modifying the original message. I thought the function would return a new copy of the orignal message, without spaces.

Is there a way I can make a temporary copy of the original `input message`, remove spaces from that, before doing my check?

Also, how do you clear allocated memory to the temp copy of the orignal input? I don't want this to linger around. Or does C automatically clears that temp char array once the code finishes it's execution in the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't actually do that.

There are two solutions:
 - Loop the string a first time to count how many non-space characters there are, so you know how much you need to allocate.

```
int count_not_empty(const char *str)
{
  int n = 0;

  for (; *str; ++str) {
    if (*str != ' ') n++;
  }
  return n + 1; // the +1 is for the nulbyte at the end
}
```

- Allocate a string as big as the one you want to trim, and pad with nulbytes at the end.

i.e.

```
char *copy_not_empty(const char *str)
{
  size_t i;
  size_t j;
  char *new = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

  for (i = j = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
  {
    if (str[i] != ' ')
      new[j++] = str[i];
  }
  for (; j <= i; j++)
    new[j] = 0; // pad with nulbytes
  return new;
}
```

---

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation and the code sample. This is working as expected now. Although it works, I have two warnings. First one: **'<': signed/unsigned mismatch** which is pointing at this line of code: `for (i = j = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {` and the second one is: **'function': different 'const' qualifiers** which is pointing at this line: `char* check_message = copy_not_empty(message);` any ideas why this might be?

Comment: uh, yeah, `strlen` returns a `size_t` which is unsigned, whereas I declared `i j` as integers. It'd be best if they were `size_t` as well! (edited)

Comment: For your second question: the argument isn't declared as const, but could be (added now)

Comment: Brilliant! thanks for that. One last question. Now that this `check_message` is a copy of the original message without spaces, what happens to the allocated memory of this temp variable? does it automatically get cleared at the end of execution in the code block? or do i need to use `free(check_message);` explicitly to de-allocate the memory?

Comment: you'll need to free it explicitly, since it was malloc'd manually.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. P.S. in your function `char *copy_not_empty(const char *str)` you've forgotten to return `new` var.

Comment: oh, true, good catch! that's what I get for not checking my answers somewhere :)

Comment: Thanks allot for your help. No more warnings in VS and code works exactly as expected.

Comment: Candidate improvements: Avoid repeated calls to `strlen(str)`.  Many compiles will not optimized and cause `O(n*n)` run-time.  If code still wants to do the unneeded pad filling, rather than `for (; j < i; j++) new[j] = 0; new[j] = 0;`, use `for (; j <= i; j++) new[j] = 0;`  Adding allocation check is good practice.

Comment: I'd argue checking malloc doesn't make any sense. If malloc fails, i'm pretty sure you strongly want your user program to crash.

Comment: also i'm sure your compiler is good enough to do LICM on stdlib functions ;).

Comment: "If malloc fails" does not necessarily lead to an immediate crash before bad things have happened.  I'd rather have code quit with an error message than crash.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if malloc fails, you have bigger concerns than your small user program.

Comment: and having to write gotos or other complex error handling cases for something like this is only clutter in your code. (unless you're just gonna `exit(1);`)

Answer (score 0):

Code broke the contract.

`const char *message` points to data that should be not modified.  `deblank(message)` attempted to modified. it --> undefined behavior.

```
bool my_pc_process_chat_message(..., const char *message) {
  if (retVal___ == true) {
    char* check_message = deblank(message);
```

A properly warning enabled compiler would warn about this - saves you time.

For more detail and ideas, post the calling code to `my_pc_process_chat_message()`.

Comment: "warning enableD" ??

Comment: @machine_1 fixedd.