# remove space in string array and count spaces C

Tags: c

I have a string line with an array. Ex:- `char array[]="I'm new to programing";`

I want to rewrite code that variable remove spaces `array[]="I'mnewtoprograming"`

I already tried to build this

```
  scanf("%[^\n]s",&line);

int len=strlen(line);
//remove space in lenth
   for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
       
       (line[i]==' ')?:newlen++;
       if (line[i]==' ')
       {
           line[i]=line[i+1];
       }
```

give me the reason that I mistake

Comment: `scanf("%[...]s", &text)` is wrong two ways: 1) it has an `'s'` too many, 2) the argument is (converted to) a pointer, shouldn't take the `&`

Comment: Please put a minimally verifiable code snippet.

Comment: `(line[i]==' ')?:newlen++;` - Use an if statement - makes the code more readable

Comment: `(line[i]==' ')?:newlen++;` should be a syntax error.

Comment: you can't just increment by one only when you find a space. You have to maintain a variable that counts the number of characters you've had to skip and add that to every assignment of the new string... `line[i] = line[i+numSpaces];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove spaces from char\* array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543918/remove-spaces-from-char-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the current position in the string and the "tail" where next char is compared to the space.

```
char *removechar(char *str, int ch)
{
    char *cpos = str, *tail = str; 

    while(*tail)
    {
        if(*tail != ch)
        {
            *cpos++ = *tail++;
        }
        else
        {
            tail++;
        }
    }
    *cpos = 0;
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make For loop for `array[]` and count `' '` spaces .
`line[i]=line[i+1];` this line is wrong .

`(line[i]==' ')?:newlen++;` this line is correct , i saw some comments that line was wrong .its same as if condition .